# Reading a Text File in Java and Converting to Multiple Vectors

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I am fairly new to Java, and I am trying to make it read a file.

I have a data text file that needs to be imported into Java as arrays.

The first row of data file is the names row. All the variables has their names in the first row and the data are clustered in the columns. I just want to import this into Java and to be able to export all the variables as I want, just as if they were vectors in MATLAB. So basically we acquire the data and tag each vector. I need the code to be as generic as possible, so it should read a variable number of columns and rows. I was able to create the array using a non-efficient method I believe. Now I need to divide the array into multiple arrays and then convert them to numbers. But I need to group the number according to the vector they belong in.

The text file is created from an Excel spreadsheet, so it basically has the columns for different measurements, which will create the vectors. Each column in another vector which contains the data in the rows.

I searched a lot of code trying to implement, but it came to a point I cannot proceed without help. Can someone possibly tell me how to proceed in any sense. Maybe even improve the reading part also, because I know it is not the best way to do like this in Java. Here is what I have in hand:

```
package Testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class Read1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fin = new FileReader("C:/jade/test/Winter_Full_clean.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fin);
            String str = "";
            int count = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line=in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (count==0) {
                    str = line;
                }
                else if (in.readLine()!=null) {
                    str = str + line;
                }
                count++;                
            }

            in.close();
            //System.out.printf(str);

            System.out.print(tokens);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("error crap" + e.getClass());
       }

    }


    //{

    //    Path yourFile = Paths.get("C:/jade/test/Winter_Full_clean.txt");
    //    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    //    List<String> lines = null;
    //    try {
    //        lines = Files.readAllLines(yourFile, charset);
    //    } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //        e.printStackTrace();
    //    }
    //    String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    //    System.out.println(arr);  
    //}



}
```

Comment: The Data file looks like this Excel File:
http://www.2shared.com/file/TMq8G4Gh/Book1.html

Comment: Is this your last code? It would not even compile (`tokens` is not defined anywhere). Also you have the data in a long `String`, not in any array.

Comment: The lines after 
//System.out.printf(str);

does not work. I got stuck after reading the data into the array.

Comment: As I said, `str` is not an array. I'd recommend you look for some information on using arrays in Java or, even better, `ArrayList`.

Comment: O.K. I will check that; as I said I am fairly new to Java and programming. Trying to get this code working as soon as possbile trying to modify the codes I can find online, since I thought this shouldn't be so hard, but it appears that it's not so simple for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that is functional and reads a text file into an array and split on tabs ( its a tsv file). You should be able to adapt this as a starting point to read in your initial data, and then based upon the data contained within your array, alter your logic to suit:

```
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) { //path is a String pointing to the file
                int lineNum = 0;
                String readLine;
                while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) { //read until end of stream
                    if (lineNum == 0) { //Skip headers, i.e. start at line 2 of your excel sheet
                        lineNum++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    String[] nextLine = readLine.split("\t"); //Split on tab
                    for (int x = 0; x < nextLine.length; x++) { //do something with ALL the lines.
                        nextLine[x] = nextLine[x].replace("\'", "");
                        nextLine[x] = nextLine[x].replace("/'", "");
                        nextLine[x] = nextLine[x].replace("\"", " ");
                        nextLine[x] = nextLine[x].replace("\\xFFFD", "");
                    }
                //In this example, to access data for a certain column, 
                //call nextLine[1] for col 1, nextLine[2] for col 2 etc. 
                } //close your loop and go to the next line in your file
} //close your resources.
```